# filterContext for ActionResult in OnResultExecuted Method of ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to filter only methods from all actions which have return type ActionResult from controller actions. 
I am getting controller name and action name from following..

```
string originController = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
string originAction = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

but how can i filter only method which have return type ActionResult?

Comment: You mean that you want only `actions` that define `ActionResult` as the return type in their method signature? or you want also `actions` that define concrete ActionResults (like `ViewResult`)?

Comment: no.. i want only actions which defined as ActionResult.. Can i get those from filterContext?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this kind of code for accessing Controllers, Actions as well as

```
  string originController = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
  string originAction = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
  string originArea = String.Empty;
   if (filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens.ContainsKey("area"))
       originArea = filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"].ToString();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this in your `Action Filter`:

```
var controllerActionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor as System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor;

if (controllerActionDescriptor == null ||
    controllerActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(ActionResult))
        {
        return;
        }

// if we got here then Action's return type is 'ActionResult'
```

**Update:**

Since you're using the `OnResultExecuted` method, try this:

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    string originController = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString();
    string originAction = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

    var actionType = filterContext.Controller.GetType().GetMethod(originAction).ReturnType;

    if (actionType != typeof(ActionResult))
        return;

    // if we got here then Action's return type is 'ActionResult'
}
```

**Update:**

As per your comment, in case there is more than one `Action` with the same name (overloading):

```
public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
{
    var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();

    var ctlr = filterContext.Controller as Controller;
    if (ctlr == null) return;
    var invoker = ctlr.ActionInvoker as ControllerActionInvoker;
    if (invoker == null) return;

    var invokerType = invoker.GetType();
    var getCtlrDescMethod = invokerType.GetMethod("GetControllerDescriptor", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var ctlrDesc = getCtlrDescMethod.Invoke(invoker, new object[] {ctlr.ControllerContext}) as ControllerDescriptor;

    var findActionMethod = invokerType.GetMethod("FindAction", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    var actionDesc = findActionMethod.Invoke(invoker, new object[] { ctlr.ControllerContext, ctlrDesc, actionName }) as ReflectedActionDescriptor;
    if (actionDesc == null) return;

    if (actionDesc.MethodInfo.ReturnType == typeof (ActionResult))
    {
        // you're in
    }
}
```

Comment: Here filterContext is of  ResultExecutedContext. i have used it in  OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext){} method. So i am unable to get filterContext.ActionDescriptor.

Comment: I revised my answer accordingly

Comment: When I am using OnResultExecuted method. Second one is working fine.. Thank you Very Much @haim .

Comment: Can i get my area name from this filterContext?

Comment: Use `filterContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"]`.

Comment: So How can you use this filterContext.Controller.GetType().GetMethod(originAction); when you have method overloading?

Comment: I revised my answer accordingly.